# Oracle DETERMINISTIC HINT Overhead

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

DETERMINISTIC HIT (as Oracle says) is used to cache the result of a function if it could be deterministic, but what is the overhead of that benefit?

I'll try to explain this better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION betwnstr (
   string_in   IN   VARCHAR2
 , start_in    IN   INTEGER
 , end_in      IN   INTEGER
)
   RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
   RETURN (SUBSTR (string_in, start_in, end_in - start_in + 1));
END;
/
```

This simple function extract the characters from BEGIN and END index from a given string.

Now i'll start to use this Function in different tables as SELECT result(other functions, procedure, package etc) and Oracle will start caching all the result from the same input.

Sure this is a wonderful result just adding a simple world on function declaration, **but what is the side effect of an intensive use of this? For example, if this function is called million of times with different input ?**

I could have many other functions as DETERMINISTICT for example:

- AN DETERMINISTIC function to calculate the difference (in DAYS) from two given date

ecc

Comment: I think the "caching" that is done for deterministic functions only happens for a single SQL execution. If it's deterministic it won't be called for the same input twice. But that "cache" is not used for the next query that uses the function.

Comment: The major benefit is when you use this function in `WHERE` clause of `SELECT` statement.  Oracle optimizer generally can not predict a cost of calling PL/SQL function. So when you use PL/SQL function for filtering the overhead of PL/SQL function call might be significant. Also functional indexes can be used only on deterministic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/function.htm#LNPLS1580):

> **DETERMINISTIC**
>
> Tells the optimizer that the function returns the same value whenever it is invoked with the same parameter values (if this is not true, then specifying DETERMINISTIC causes unpredictable results). If the function was invoked previously with the same parameter values, the optimizer can use the previous result instead of invoking the function again.

The optimizer **can** use the previous result, but doesn't have too; this is just asserting that if it needed to call it multiple times for the same parameter values - generally within a single query - it can choose to only make the call once, since you're promised it that it would always get the same result. That doesn't necessarily imply that function results could be cached somewhere between queries, though they may be cached by other mechanisms (I think).

When Oracle does cache things it manages the cache size to stay within available memory, and to optimise the memory available for various functionality. Basically you don't need to worry about side-effects from making a function deterministic, assuming you're using it properly.

There's more [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_function.htm#LNPLS1918), including how this relates to function-based indexes etc.

Comment: Yes there are two caching directives: `DETERMINISTIC` and `CACHE RESULTS`. The 1st is statement level only.

Comment: @ibre5041 - yes, there are further links from the docs to result-cached functions, but that seemed to be going a bit off-topic.

Comment: So functions as i have described above, could be marked as deterministinc without warring in some strange memory errors in an Production enviroment? Sure... the function must marked DETERMINISTICT if it really is:)

Comment: @Mistre83 - if anything it might make a query use less temporary memory, I suppose. It's not going to have any effects on memory outside an individual query though.

Comment: @Mistre83 it depends on place where you use it. IMHO if you use it in WHERE clause in a query where you join several tables you SHOULD mark it.